# Multi-auth with verification email issue

Tags: laravel

I have a `multi-auth` application with verification email functionality. I am using the laravel's default email verification functionality, `verified` middleware. The verification email is sent via Laraval's `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` method for each role.

*Functionality:* There are 2 roles. The main role is `company` which can register and can create `employee` role (the `employee` role can not register directly).

Here is my code:

```
companies:
id | ... | email_verified_at | ...

employees:
id | company_id | ... | email_verified_at | ...


email_verified_at = timestamp : default null
```

Company.php

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Company extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    ...
}
```

Employee.php

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Employee extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    ...
}
```

RegisterController.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

...

use App\Company;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    ...

    protected function register()
    {
        # validating
        $arrayPost = $this->validator(request()->all())->validate();

        # models
        $Company = new Company();

        # accessing methods
        if(($company = $Company->_create($arrayPost))['success'] == false)
        {
            return redirect()->withErrors()->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            $company->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
        }

        # returning
        return redirect()->route('site.registration.success');
    }

    ...
}
```

EmployeeController.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
...

use App\Employee;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function store()
    {
        $arrayPost = $this->validator(request()->all());

        if($arrayPost->fails())
        {
            ...
        }

        $Employee = new Employee();

        # accessing methods
        if(($employee = $Employee->_create($arrayPost->validate()))['success'] == false)
        {
            return redirect()->withErrors()->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            $employee->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
        }

        # returning
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }

    ...
}
```

The verification links are working fine. However, when it comes to updating the record then only the `companies` table is getting updated not the `employees` table. Even though, The verification link is generated form the `EmployeeController` and with newly created employee's id.

Generated link for `employee`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/verify/43/9c616a854c72197bfee10c1ffcb0446fc89f8f86?expires=1595066822&signature=ebfc95ba694f471f6c7cf037054a7700707aa9d028786c201528a1d5c6b0673f
```